# Why does my VB.NET code create a list of items all the same

Tags: .net, vb.net

This sounds so very simple I can't believe I have to post it, but I've scraped my entire code down to the basics (5000 lines of code down to this), because during a rework I can't understand why this is breaking the program.

This is basically code that goes to a blog page, saves the page as as htmldocument, checks if it has a "more" link, saves that page, and so on.
brwsEEPage is a WebBrowser object

```
    Public Class EEMain
    Private Pages As New List(Of EEPage)
    Private Sub brwsEEPage_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles brwsEEPage.DocumentCompleted
        ' This is doublechecking that the whole document is actually completed
        Static complete As Boolean
        If (e.Url.AbsolutePath <> (DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)).Url.AbsolutePath) Then
            Return
        Else
            If Not complete Then
                Dim p As New EEPage
                p.Doc = brwsEEPage.Document
                Pages.Add(p)
                If p.NextPage IsNot Nothing Then
                    Beep()
                    brwsEEPage.Navigate(p.NextPage)
                Else
                    complete = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If complete = True Then
            For Each page As EEPage In Pages
                lstPageList.Items.Add(page.Doc.Url.ToString)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then the class for the page (a lot more code to go in here)

```
Public Class EEPage
    Private _doc As HtmlDocument
    Private _nextPage As String
    Public Property Doc As HtmlDocument
        Get
            Return _doc
        End Get
        Set(value As HtmlDocument)
            _doc = value
            SetNextPage()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property NextPage As String
        Get
            Return _nextPage
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _nextPage = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub SetNextPage()
        NextPage = Nothing
        For Each element As HtmlElement In Me.Doc.Links
            If element.InnerHtml.Contains("Older Posts") Then
                NextPage = Parsers.ParseLinkFromHtmlElement(element)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

For some reason I can't see, every EEpage in Pages seems to turn out the same.  the lstPageList (a listbox) shows the same url for every page.
Since I'm adding the page to the list before initiating the browse to the next page, I can't see why each subsequent browserpage is overwriting the previous.

I'm not used to using Brow'veser objects, and certainly not used to having to rely on asynchronous code (which is why I written it this way).

It feels like I've missed a "New" initiator, or used a byref, but I've clearly not done that.... so where did I go wrong?

Comment: Some idea a bit off-course, I think you don't have to use WebBrowser if your website is not using some fancy obfuscated javascript stuff to load the pages dynamically. Try using  `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString` to download the raw Html (I used this a bit obselete class because it is easy to use and it blocks the thread so you do not have to worry about multithreading, you just have to run all the things on a new thread), then use `XDocument` to parse it and get your link desired.

Comment: That sounds perfect... for this part at least.
I don't know what this entails, so I'll have to Google some of the bits you've said.
It also sounds like it might significantly speed up this part of my code, which at the end of the day, was only needed to create a list of URLs.

I'll wait to see what other responses I get, because later on, I'll need the actual page, including selecting some other links from it.

Comment: Maybe there is something to do with the implementation of the `Document` property of the WebBrowser. Maybe the object remains the same but its content gets changed. And as you only saves the reference in EEpage, they are all pointing to a same object, thus making every Document.Url the same. You can try get the `Document.Url.ToString()` and `DocumentText` (since they are strings they should be cloned automatically properly instead of just storing references), and store them in EEPage instead of the HtmlDocument. That is only a guess though since I seldom use WebBrowser. Try if it works?